# length of dropdown in angularjs-dropdown-multiselect

Tags: javascript, angularjs, drop-down-menu

Hi for a particular requirement, I am using the [angularjs-dropdown-multiselect](http://dotansimha.github.io/angularjs-dropdown-multiselect/) (I wanted a dropdown multiselect with selectAll and unSelectAll). I am facing difficulties in customizing the view.

1) If I keep "scrollable" as false (default), sometimes the data is huge, and all the data is shown in the dropdown, the dropdown becomes very long (shows all the 50 choices). If I keep "scrollable" attribute as true, by default it takes height of the dropdown as 300px. This is not dynamic height. So even if there are 1-2 options, the dropdown shown is 300px. How do I resolve it? I want to keep a max-height and the length should be dynamic if it is lesser than that.

2) If the list is small, the scrollbars are still visible (it is disabled), how do I remove the scrollbars if the list is small (lesser than max-height)?

Comment: if angularjs-dropdown-multiselect is the not the way to go, I would like to get some suggestions for some other library which gives this requirement - dropdown, multiselect and selectall/unselectall options

Comment: I could not solve this so far, so I made a hackable multiselect dropdown with select all/unselect all option, take a look at this if needed -> https://github.com/akashrajkn/sf-multiselect

Answer (score 0):

I worked on a simple directive for multi-select dropdown just to avoid dependency on other external libraries for a simple use. If you are looking for "Select all" & "Unselect all", with dynamic height configurable option (including custom icons..), you might want to take a look at -

https://github.com/rajush/ng-dropdown-multiselect

Simple, but gets the job done.